# ImageView getLayoutParams width unit

Tags: java, android, width, layoutparams

If I want to set the width/height of an ImageView programmatically in Java, like this:

```
image_view.getLayoutParams().width = 200;
```

What's the unit of those "200"? Is it px/dp?
Does it look "the same" on every device? (That means: Is it extremely big on tablets and totally small on smartphones?)

Answer (score 3):

It is in pixels. But to be device independent we need to set value in dp.

So, in your code you can write a swicth case and based on screen resolution which you can get from device metrices, can set the value accordingly like this:

```
   DisplayMetrics metrics = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
   if(metrics.density == 1)
        //
    else if(metrics.density == 2)
        //
    else if(metrics.density == 1.5)
        //
```

Also you can change px values to dp using formula:

px = dp * (dpi/160)

Answer (score 2):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html

Fairly sure it's pixels.

> the height, either MATCH_PARENT, WRAP_CONTENT or a fixed size in pixels

Comment: I see, so it's very small on a screen with higher resolution, right?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not an Android developer, and I can't confirm this 100%.

Comment: yes. since you set the value in px, so it is seen very small for large devices.